# serializing an RSAKeyValue property in Serializable class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, cryptography, rsa

I have a class in my C# project marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute.  It has a property of type [`RSAKeyValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.rsakeyvalue.aspx):

```
[XmlElement(PUBLIC_KEY_TAG_NAME)]
public RSAKeyValue Key { get; private set; }
```

When I try to serialize an instance of my class to XML and then deserialize that XML back to an instance of my class, I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: System.Security.Cryptography.KeySizes cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

This occurs when I call `XmlSerializer.Serialize`.  I'm sure it's because of the `RSAKeyValue` property in my class since all the other properties that get serialized are simple strings.  What can I do about this?  Should I maybe make my own wrapper class around an `RSAKeyValue` instance that properly serializes/deserializes?

Here is some sample XML that could be deserialized into an `RSAKeyValue` instance:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>long string here...</Modulus>
  <Exponent>short string here</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the XML Serializer ignores the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Second, if the class does not have a default constructor, then you can't serialize it using the XML Serializer, period.

What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps you can accomplish the same thing using the Data Contract Serializer?

---

Create a class that contains just a Modulus and an Exponent. Fill that class from an RSAKeyValue. Serialize your custom class. After deserializing, use it to create a new RSAKeyValue.

Comment: I want to be able to store the Modulus and Exponent parts of the `RSAKeyValue` in an XML document alongside other data.  I want to be able to read XML from a file and have it parsed out into an instance of my class, then access the `Key` property and get an instance of some class containing the Modulus and Exponent that were stored in the XML.

Comment: Then you just answered your own question. Create a class that contains just a Modulus and an Exponent. Fill that class from an RSAKeyValue. Serialize your custom class. After deserializing, use it to create a new RSAKeyValue.

Comment: Hmph.  With your fancy ideas...  ;)  Working on that now; thanks!

Comment: John, you should post your comment as an answer, because that's what I ended up doing and it worked for me.  I'd mark yours as the selected answer!